# Bot framework v4 : Oauth implementation

Tags: botframework

I am using the web chat for testing the bot skill.

1. OAuthPrompt dialog does the authentication, but it requires the user to enter the authentication code in the chat window to complete the authentication. How to implement a mechanism without the need to enter the code?
2. I need to check if the user is authenticated before responding to any communication. Should this be implemented in OnTurnAsync or OnMembersAddedAsync?

Answer (score 0):

1. This  is called the Magic code. To be able to work without the code you need to use Enhanced Authentication. More about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-security-enhanced?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)
2. That is done in the onTokenResponseEvent. You can check the sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/18.bot-authentication)